# Equivalent of End / Response.End in razor?

Tags: asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I'm trying to stop the rest of a page loading based on some parameters; but am not sure of the correct syntax.

```
@if(dayRes + dayTri == 2){<text>Sorry, etc</text> @Response.End}
```

The above throws this error: **CS1502:
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments**

Any ideas?

Comment: @ doesn't mean print! it starts a code block as your block starts with @if, you can't start a nested block

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your code tries to print Response.End to the page.

You can just write (in your code block)

```
return;
```

to stop running the generated Execute() method.

You can also call End as a method inside of your code block:

```
Response.End();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I'm not sure how to integrate it into the code though (apologies - beginner here) `@if(count + count2 == 2){<text>Hello World</text> @Response.End();}` - that still throws the CS1502 compilation error

Comment: @Tom: @ means print. You don't want @.

Comment: FYI, return; worked great for me but Response.End() was what I tried before finding this post.  It did end the request but did not output what was in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (@Model.Container == null)
{
    <span style="font-weight: bold; ">Container Not Found </span style="font-weight: bold; ">
    return;
}
```